# display the number of divs dynamically according to the input number given in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want the divs to appear according to the number obtained in the input. If input is 3; I want 3 maindiv blocks to appear.If it changes to 1; only 1 maindiv block should appear. Someone suggest the solution?

```js
function showTrips(){
        var argument = document.getElementById("Number_of_trips");
        var value = argument.options[argument.selectedIndex].text;
        var main = document.getElementById("mainform");
        var mains = document.getElementById("maindiv");
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
            newdiv.innerHTML = mains.innerHTML;

        for (var i = 1; i < value; i++)
        {
        
            main.appendChild(newdiv);

             }

        }
```

```html
 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary panel-group ">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <label for="Number of trips">Number_Of_Trips:</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="Numberoftrips" onchange="showTrips()" >
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form role="form" id="mainform" >
        <div class="container" >
            <div class="row" id="maindiv">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary panel-group ">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Trip Details</h3>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </form>
```

I have attached the html code now.

Comment: fiddle it please with whole code

Comment: For this kind of question you should add your relevant HTML and CSS. It's worth noting that an `id`, in HTML, cannot contain white-space. And you'll be appending the same `newdiv` multiple times, rather than a new copy of that node.

Comment: Please be clear with your question. When you will call that javascript function. Onchange of select list and do you want to insert new div everytime or existing div which is hidden????

Answer (score 1):

Your id 'Number of trips' is not a valid id it should not contain any blank space.

if it contain

```
    <select id="Numberoftrips">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" >2</option>
    <option value="3"selected="selected">3</option>
</select>
```

Using jquery you can try

```
        $(function(){
 $('#Numberoftrips').change(function(){
var argument = document.getElementById("Numberoftrips");
var value = argument.options[argument.selectedIndex].value;
            var main = document.getElementById("mainform");
            var mains = document.getElementById("maindiv");
     $( "#maindiv" ).empty();
            for (var i = 1; i <= value; i++)
            {


               var div = document.createElement('div');
maindiv.appendChild(div);
    div.className = 'aClassName';
    div.innerHTML = '<span class="">Hello world.</span>';

                 }});
});
```

don't forget to add link

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

see link on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0f4wcaL6/)

Comment: +1 for using jQuery. But I think he wants to use javascript. if you update your code to javascript then it might meet his requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.
**[updated]**

```js
function showTrips(){
        var argument = document.getElementById("Numberoftrips");
        var value = argument.options[argument.selectedIndex].text;

  var ni = document.getElementById("container");
  var mains = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
  var innerHt=mains[0].innerHTML;
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  var divs=[];

  while (ni.firstChild) {
    ni.removeChild(ni.firstChild);
}
  for (var i = 1; i < value; i++)
        {
   var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
   newdiv.innerHTML = innerHt;
   var divIdName = 'my'+i+'Div';
   newdiv.className="row";
   newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
   divs[i]=newdiv;
   ni.appendChild(divs[i]);

        }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary panel-group ">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <label for="Number of trips">Number_Of_Trips:</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="Numberoftrips" onchange="javascript:showTrips();" >
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form role="form" id="mainform" >
        <div id="container" class="container" >
            <div class="row" id="maindiv">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary panel-group ">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Trip Details</h3>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: I tried this but doesn't work. It actualy appends multiple divs and not the exact number required.

Comment: Ok.. I got your point.. But When you want to call your showTrips function then?

Comment: I want to call it using onchange event in the select list.

Comment: ok.. thats fine.. now do you want to insert a new div every time or want to show a set of hidden divs based on the selected option.

Comment: Then I think @Rasel has answered your question with some jQuery included... do you want to do it in pure javascript?

Comment: yeah. But its not working if there other than text in the html that is being assigned to div.innerhtml ; it is not working.

Comment: Other than text..?? can you elaborate.. Please explain the proper scenario.. What you want inside and what you are looking for.. Will definitely solve this...

Comment: I have mentioned it in the code .I want the id='maindiv' block to repeat again and again as per the input.

Comment: <div class="row" id="maindiv">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary panel-group ">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Trip Details</h3>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

Comment: Above I have mentioned the maindiv block.

Comment: I have updated the answer... Just try once.. works fine for me.. let me know any changes u want..